# Allow textarea having html value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.net MVC5 application and I want to send html code to the DB via Text area but this one doesn't seem to be allowing it. Here is a piece of code of what I'm trying to do :

```
    <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PRETEXT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, cols = 50, rows = 10 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PRETEXT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm wondering if is there any possibility to make it accept html tags.

Comment: What does it look like rendered?

Comment: It renders me an error saying that ASP.net has detected some html script that may be dangerous...

Comment: You could encode your input with client-side code (JavaScript, for example) before you post it, and then decode it server-side if you wish (`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`) or better yet store it encoded in your database if you don't have to manipulate it server-side and decode it on the client when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decorate your `PRETEXT` property with the `AllowHtml` attribute :

```
[AllowHtml]
public string PRETEXT { get; set; }
```